# How to handle a question which is a duplicate of a question in a different stack exchange?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

In a comment to a question, [OpenStreetMap export](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/64834/2217), I noted that the question was already answered on Geographic Information Stackexchange.
Should this be considered a duplicate and closed as a duplicate, or is a question (or answer) only considered a  duplicate only if the question it is already asked (or answered) on BSE?

Answer (score 3):

If it was a duplicate (this case it is not) and fits on the other site, you could flag it and ask it to be moved to the proper site where they could mark it as a duplicate.
However it seems like the question you linked to is not what the OP is looking for.

In this case the best thing to do is to simply write an answer to the question on BSE. You can use parts of the other site's answer, so long as you give the proper attribution.

I would suggest any time there is a question that does fit our scope, but has already been asked and answered else where, you write your own answer here. By all means you can link to the other answer, even quote parts of it if you need to. Chances are that the question on BSE will be a bit different then the one on any other site. (Makes it easy to write an answer that is your own.)

It is as simple as this: There is a question that has not been answered yet on BSE, answer it.

SE has no system to close question as dups across sites, each site is separate while still part of the whole SE universe. Yes, questions are only considered a dup if the dup is on the same site (that can lead to some strange results, but it is what we have.)